# Prove that $x^2 + xy + y^2 \ge 0$ by contradiction

Tags: inequality, polynomials

Using the fact that $x^2 + 2xy + y^2 = (x + y)^2 \ge 0$, show that the assumption $x^2 + xy + y^2 < 0$ leads to a contradiction...
So do I start off with...

"Assume that $x^2 + xy + y^2 <0$, then blah blah blah"?

It seems true...because then I go $(x^2 + 2xy + y^2) - (x^2 + xy + y^2) \ge 0$.
It becomes $2xy - xy \ge 0$, then $xy \ge 0$.
How is this a contradiction? 
I think I'm missing some key point.

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$?

Comment: It's amazing how all of the answers seemed to appear at once :)

Comment: I think it's just all real numbers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Suppose that $x^2+xy+y^2<0$; then $x^2+2xy+y^2<xy$, so $(x+y)^2<xy$. Subtracting $3xy$ from both sides of the original inequality, we see that $x^2-2xy+y^2<-3xy$, so $(x-y)^2<-3xy$. Squares are non-negative, so on the one hand $xy>0$, and on the other hand $-3xy>0$ and therefore $xy<0$.

Comment: how do you get x^2 + 2xy + y^2 < xy ?

Comment: @user96110: By adding $xy$ to both sides of $x^2+xy+y^2<0$.

Comment: thanks, and also, how did (x-y)^2 < -3xy become 0 < -3xy ?

Comment: @user96110: $0\le(x-y)^2<-3xy$, since $(x-y)^2$ is a square.

Comment: How did you for from (x+y)^2 to (x-y)^2? Is it a typo?

Comment: @Kevin: I didn’t get from $(x+y)^2$ to $(x-y)^2$. Starting with $x^2+xy+y^2<0$ I made two independent calculations; in one I added $xy$ to both sides, and in the other I subtracted $3xy$ from both sides.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense =)

Answer (score 11):

By completing square,

$$x^2+xy+y^2 = x^2+2x\frac{y}{2}+\frac{y^2}{4} + \frac{3y^2}{4} = \left(x+\frac{y}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3y^2}{4}\ge 0$$

Comment: Sorry if this is kind of dumb, but i don't really get this. how would i complete the square?

Comment: By completing square, you wish to find a form $x^2+xy+y^2 = (x+p)^2+q = x^2+2px+p^2+q$. Therefore, you should actually take $p=\frac{y}{2}$ to match the $xy$ term, then split the $y^2$ term to $\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2$ as $p^2$ and the remaining portion as $q$.

Answer (score 4):

Assume $x^2+xy+y^2<0$. Adding and subtracting $xy$ on the left-hand side gives $x^2+2xy+y^2-xy=(x+y)^2-xy<0$, and therefore $0\leq(x+y)^2<xy$. Conversely, $x^2+xy+y^2<0$ implies $xy<-(x^2+y^2)\leq0$. Combining these, we have $$xy<0<xy,$$ a clear contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming everything in the picture is a real number, you've arrived at $xy\ge 0$, and so $x^2+xy+y^2\ge 0$. This contradicts our assumption.

Comment: i think i kind of get this. because even if x, y <0 ,the x^2 and y^2 would make the positive. Right? So then it would have to be >= 0.

Comment: You had already arrived at the conclusion $xy\ge 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to see this is as follows:

Suppose $x^2+xy+y^2 <0$, then $xy<-x^2-y^2< 0$, hence $2xy<xy<-x^2-y^2$ and thus $x^2+2xy+y^2<0$, which is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

Averaging the inequalities $(x+y)^2\ge0$ and $x^2+y^2\ge0$ we get $\frac12(x+y)^2+\frac12(x^2+y^2)\ge0$, that is $x^2+xy+y^2\ge0$, contradicting the assumption that $x^2+xy+y^2\lt0$.

Answer (score 0):

I will give an answer, by trichotomy law, which is valid even for integers:

1. If $xy=0$, then $x^2+xy+y^2=x^2+y^2≥0$.
2. If $xy>0$, then $x^2+xy+y^2>0$.
3. If $xy<0$, thus $2xy<xy$. So, $x^2+xy+y^2>x^2+2xy+y^2=(x+y)^2≥0$.

Comment: Why do you mention the integers?

Comment: Because this proof is valid for integer and real numbers too. However, the proof by completing square is valid only for real numbers